# Updated : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore]

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

android/app/build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "cmon.com"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Error:

```
G:\Flutter\cmon\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] G:\Flutter\cmon\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

How to modify the above given default versions. What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually add the minimum sdk version like this

```dart
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cmon.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In an Android Studio project, you have to edit the `build.gradle` file. In a flutter project, it is found at the path `./android/app/build.gradle`.

The parameter that needs to be changed in minSdkVersion is 19

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    //This is the part that needs to be changed, previously was 16
    minSdk 19 
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}
```

Android SDK 16-18 is only a Best-effort platforms.
Best-effort means supported through community testing, are platforms we believe we support through coding practices and ad-hoc testing, but rely on the community for testing.

Here is the reference link.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms#supported-google-tested-platforms

Answer (score 1):

In your android/app/build.gradle flie,

comment this line - `minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion` 
and just add `minSdkVersion 21` or `flutter.minSdkVersion=21`

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.phone_vrification"
    minSdkVersion 21
   // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```